# JPQL gives back java.langObject, instad of the expected type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have an `Employee` class. A `Worker` class extends `Employee`, and `Leader` class extends `Worker`.

Every `Leader` has a list `public List workersResponsibleFor = new ArrayList<>();`. Which is a Join table, to illustrate if a `Leader` is responsible for one or many `Workers`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="EMP_TYPE")
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
public abstract class Employee implements Printable, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "employee_id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "position")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Position position;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Double salary;

    @Transient
    public List<Project> projectsWorkingOn = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee() {
    }
}
```

`Worker`:

```
@Entity
public class Worker extends Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "worker_id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    public Worker() {
    }
}
```

`Leader`:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Leader extends Worker {

    public Leader() {
    }

    public Leader(Position position, String name, Double salary) {
        super(position, name, salary);
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="WORKERS_RESPONSIBLE_FOR",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="RES_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="FOR_ID")})
    public List<Worker> workersResponsibleFor = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The problem is, every time I try to get a Worker back with the following method:

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
private static final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

public Worker exampleQuery() {
        Worker w;
        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select e1, e2 from Employee e1 join e1.workersResponsibleFor e2 WHERE e1.name LIKE 'James%'");
            w = (Worker) query.getSingleResult();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
            entityManagerFactory.close();
        }
        System.out.println(w.getName());
        return w;
    }
```

Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.company.employees.Worker`

I get a `java.lang.Object` back, insted of a `Worker`. But all my other methods are able to return Workers, so could be the problem with the query I'm using? Thanks

Comment: Feel free to ACCEPT answers when they answer your question. And if they dont then kindly say why not!

Answer (score 0):

JPQL of

```
select e1, e2 from Employee e1 join e1.workersResponsibleFor e2 WHERE ...
```

will always return rows of type `Object[]` (and the message tells you exactly that), since that is what the JPA spec defines it to do. And if you look at element 0 it will be of the type of e1, and element 1 will be of the type of e2. Suggest you look at the JPA spec or the documentation of whichever implementation you use.

If you had instead selected just the candidate alias then you get a row of type of e1. Again, defined in the JPA spec!